# JOB Scheduling Algorithm with given set of machines

Tags: algorithm

m unit jobs need to be scheduled on n machines. (m>n) All the jobs require the same amount of processing time, but a job cannot be processed on any machine, it can only be processed on a subset of machines. You are given pij, pij is TRUE if the ith job can be processed on a jth machine, FALSE, otherwise. Design an efficient algorithm to schedule the jobs on these machines to minimize the maximum no. of jobs processed on a machine.

Comment: This isn't a place for asking homework questions.

Comment: Can we use sort jobs based on start time and use a Binary Search tree to store (ET, Machine, Jobid).?

Comment: Please add your question directly to the post. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Homework help is specifically addressed there.

Comment: Do you actually mean to minimize the maximum number of jobs scheduled on a machine or do you mean to minimize the makespan?

Comment: I suppose by _efficient_ you mean _polynomial_; please clarify whether _m_ ist constant or part of the input.

Comment: m is part of input.....

Comment: if Job 1 can be scheduled on machine {1}
and Job 2 can be scheduled on the machine {1,2} then we have to schedule the job 2 on machine 2 and not 1 if both machines are available to minimize the maximum no. of jobs processed on a machine.